# Node.js 'headers already sent' when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, node.js

I keep getting this error (after a certain amount of time) when i refresh the my 'members area' after login. I use response.redirect to redirect to the area (success) or back to sign in form (error). How can i fix this?

```
app.get('/sellers/login', function(request, response) {
    if(request.session.sellerId){
        response.redirect( '/sellers/area?logged_in=true');
    }
    else{
        response.render('pages/sellers-login');
    }
});

    app.post('/authenticate', function(request, response) {
    if(request.session.sellerId){
        response.redirect('/area?logged_in=true');
    }
    else{
        db.authenticate(request.body.loginid, function(err, results) {
        if(err){ 
            response.redirect('/sellers/login?err=1&logged_in=false&type=db');
        }
        else{
            if(results.length >=1){
                var hash = results[0]['hash'];
                var seller_id = results[0]['id'];
                bcrypt.compare(request.body.password, hash, function(err, res) {
                    if(res){
                        request.session.sellerId = seller_id;
                        response.redirect('/sellers/area?logged_in=true');
                    }
                    else{
                        response.redirect('/sellers/login?err=1&logged_in=false&type=pMatch');
                    }
                });
            }
            else{
                response.redirect('/sellers/login?err=1&logged_in=false&type=user');
            }
        }

        });
    }

});
app.get('/sellers/area', function(request, response) {
    if(request.session.sellerId){
        response.render('pages/sellers-area');
    }
    else{
        response.redirect('/sellers/login?not_logged_in=true');
    }

});
```

Comment: I don't see anything obvious there.  What is happening in the middleware prior?

Comment: I've added more to the code.

Comment: The error shouldn't happen anymore in the shown code. Are you sure that you restarted the server, and if so are you sure that is still happens at the shown code, did you check the error message for the file and line number?

Answer (score 2):

```
if(request.session.sellerId){
    response.redirect('/area?logged_in=true');
}

db.authenticate(request.body.loginid, function(err, results) {
    // .... 
});
```

You send the header when `request.session.sellerId` evaluates to `true` by calling the `response.redirect`, but you continue with the the `db.authenticate` afterwards.
Inside of that callback you will do another redirect, even when your redirect for that response has already taken place.

Inside of the `db.authenticate` you have the same problem with the `if(err)`

**EDIT**

you need to use an `else` block (or a `return`) for both the `if (request.session.sellerId)`  and the `if (err) {`

```
if (request.session.sellerId) {
  response.redirect('/area?logged_in=true');
} else {
  db.authenticate(request.body.loginid, function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
      response.redirect('/sellers/login?err=1&logged_in=false&type=db');
    } else if (results.length >= 1) {
      var hash = results[0]['hash'];
      var seller_id = results[0]['id'];
      bcrypt.compare(request.body.password, hash, function(err, res) {
        if (res) {
          request.session.sellerId = seller_id;
          response.redirect('/sellers/area?logged_in=true');
        } else {
          response.redirect('/sellers/login?err=1&logged_in=false&type=pMatch');
        }
      });
    } else {
      response.redirect('/sellers/login?err=1&logged_in=false&type=user');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I was about to write the same :D It's a common misconception that `response.redirect()` (or `response.send()`) somehow miraculously stops the rest of the function from executing.

Comment: @robertklep this definitely needs to be corrected, but I'm not sure if this is the error message for this situation. I would have expected something like `connection already closed`  or something similar, because after the first redirect it would close the connection to the client. But maybe they check if the headers where already send first before they check if the connection is still valid.

Comment: Sorry, how should i fix it? What would the correct code look like?

Comment: I added an else block and still got the same error.

Comment: @t.niese calling `response.redirect()` twice will cause the _"Can't set headers after they are sent"_ error.

Answer (score 0):

I think i've found precisely where the error originates from which lies in the db.authenticate

```
 //db.js  
 exports.authenticate = function(loginid, callback) {
      var sql = "select ...";
      pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if(err) { 
            console.log(err); 
            callback(true); 
            return; 
        }
        connection.query(sql, [loginid], function(err, results) {
          connection.release();
          if(err) { 
                console.log(err); 
                callback(true); 
                return; 
            }
            callback(false, results);
        });
        connection.on('error', function(err) { 
            console.log(err); 
            connection.release();
            callback(true);
            return;     
        });
      });
    };
```

The `connection.on('error',...` gets called, so the `callback(true)` activates causing this error.

Comment: Yes thats the same problem as with the others I described. I don't know the db library, but I would guess, that if the `err` in the `query` callback is set, that then also the `error` callback will be called, so the callback will be called twice.

Comment: Thanks, you saved me a whole lot of pain! muchas gracias

Comment: No problem, glad that you where able to track down the remaining problem yourself.